# When are the product of minimal maps also minimal?

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I am struggling to answer this question from Intro to Dyn Systems, Brin:

Exercise 2.1.10 Assume that f and g are minimal. Find necessary and sufficient conditions
for f × g to be minimal.

My attempt:

Let f: X → X and g: Y →Y be continuous maps of compact metric spaces.
f × g is minimal if every orbit is dense in X × Y.

From a previous result, the closure of the forward orbit of f × g is equal to the closure of the forward orbit of f times the closure of the forward orbit of g if, and only if, (x, g(y)) is inside the closure
f×g (x, y).

I'm now stuck on how to use this, but I think it might be related to ensuring (x, g(y)) is inside the closure of f×g(x, y).

Could anyone also suggest an example that would illustrate why the condition is necessary?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. Here's a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Also, use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to make your maths look pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:x\mapsto (x+\alpha\bmod 1)$ be a map with dense orbits on the unit circle, that is, $α$ is irrational. Let $g=f^{\circ2}$ be the map for the still irrational $2α$. Then $f\times g$ will move along the lines $2x-y=2x_0-y_0=const. \pmod 1$ on the product torus, meaning it does not have dense orbits. $2x_0-g(y_0)=2x_0-y_0-2α \pmod 1$ does not lie on this same line.